# Use Web Service In Nginx configuration File

Tags: c++, c, linux, nginx

See this configuration

```
location ~* ^/dl/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9]+)(.*)$ {
root /home/GodOFWar/public_html/;
secure_link $1,$2;
secure_link_md5 oH4fJ4KiON6sRT5tXDC1$3$2;
if ($secure_link = "") {
return 403;
}
if ($secure_link = "0") {
return 403;
}
rewrite ^/dl/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$3 break;
}
```

After the token and expiry time are checked (before rewrite), I want to call a module with the operation that the  token and user IP are sent to the web service; if the output of the web service is True, the file is downloaded, and if it is False, a Username/password is received and sent to the web service as in Http Auth Basic.
If the output of the web service is True, the file is downloaded, and if it is False, error 404 is given

For Example :

http://www.example.com/dl/GghBgdpQluCkx17nbBY29w/1440849227/user/John/Files/Video.Mp4

```
/*
  * After the token and expiry time are checked
  * Token And user IP are Sent to the web service :
  * WS : http://www.example.com/checkToken/GghBgdpQluCkx17nbBY29w/52.152.62.145
*/
if(True) {
  rewrite ^/dl/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$3 break;
}
else {
    /*
     * a Username/password is received and sent to the web service   similar Http Auth          
      Module.
     * WS : http://www.example.com/checkUser/GodOfWar/123456
    */
    if(True) {
      rewrite ^/dl/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /$3 break;
    }
    else {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem